# Getting Intel-syntax asm output from icc, instead of the default AT&T syntax?

Tags: c, assembly, syntax, icc, intel-syntax

I am stuck at a problem. I've been using gcc to compile/assemble my C code for a while and got used to reading Intel assembly syntax. I used the `-masm=intel` flag when generating the assembly files.

Yet recently, due to company migrations, they obtained Intel's icc, claiming it is better. So now I need to use icc, but it was strange that it has the default assembly syntax as AT&T. I tried to change it but it didn't work, so I contacted Intel support and they also don't know and each person gave me a contradicting answer.

Is there a way to integrate gcc and icc so that I use icc's compiling "superiority" while at the same time compiling to intel's syntax with gcc?

I am using ubuntu and got the icc version 12.x

Comment: How difficult would it be to move the inline asm out into separate assembly source files and build those using a suitable assembler ?

Comment: Also, you do realise that there is nothing to stop you linking gcc-compiled source files with other icc-compiled sources ?

Comment: @Paul: I dont know if you understood the question. I dont want to assemble...I just want to read assembly files, and I am not using inline assembly! I want to use the '-S' to look at assembly code

Comment: OK - so this is the same as your previous question on this subject ? (It looks like you deleted the original question ?).

Answer (score 3):

This flag?

```
   -use_msasm     Support  Microsoft  style  assembly  language  insertion
                  using MASM style syntax and, if requested, output assem-
                  bly in MASM format
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20120728043315/http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/icc.html

Comment: The link has died, and the `-use_msasm` flag doesn't work either

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc link resurrected, it is just the man page for icc.  You may have to scavenge the release notes of your version to follow the changes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `-masm=intel` [works in ICC](https://github.com/mattgodbolt/compiler-explorer/issues/72) just like Clang and GCC, at least in the current latest version in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27int+testFunction(int*+input,+int+length)+%7B%0A++int+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+length%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++sum+%2B%3D+input%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.29597598988003,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc18,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-masm%3Dintel%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+icc+18.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.65538305439238,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc1301,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-masm%3Dintel%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+icc+13.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:36.04864095572759,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) (13.0.1). I tried loading the *sum over array* example and it generates the below assembly

```
testFunction(int*, int):
        xor       eax, eax                                      #2.11
        test      esi, esi                                      #3.23
        jle       ..B1.18       # Prob 50%                      #3.23
        movsxd    rdx, esi                                      #3.3
...
```

whereas specifying `-use_msasm` like in Steve-o's answer doesn't work at all

The [official man page from Intel](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt) said that it's `-use-msasm` and not `-use_msasm` but that doesn't work either

> [`-use-msasm` (i32, i32em only)](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt)
>
> - Support  Microsoft*  style  assembly  language  insertion using  MASM style syntax and, if requested, output assembly in MASM format.
> - Note:   GNU inline assembler  (asm)  code  and  Microsoft inline  assembler (msasm) code cannot be used together in the same translation unit.

However that's for ICC 9.x in 2006 which was too long ago, and the option might have been changed somewhere between 9.x and 13.x

I dug a little bit further and realized that at least since [ICC 16.0](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/693602) the option is only for assembly blocks in source code and not for outputting Intel syntax

> ### [use-msasm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/693602)
>
> Enables the use of blocks and entire functions of assembly code within a C or C++ file.
>
> ### Description
>
> This option enables the use of blocks and entire functions of assembly code within a C or C++ file.
>
> It allows a Microsoft* MASM-style inline assembly block not a GNU*-style inline assembly block.
>
> ### Alternate Options
>
> `-fasm-blocks`

As you can see it's just an alias for `-fasm-blocks`. Moreover the [`-use-asm` option was deprecated](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/693077) although I don't know the fate of `-use-msasm`

References

- [Intel® C++ Compiler for Linux* - 9.x manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-linux-9x-manuals)
- [Intel® C++ Compiler 16.0 User and Reference Guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cplusplus-compiler-16.0-user-and-reference-guide)
- [Intel® C++ Compiler 17.0 Developer Guide and Reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/682403)

Comment: Offtop: what are `#x.xx` numbers?

Comment: @pmor see [this same question from me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28905885/995714)