# Modify and assemble .s file

Tags: c, assembly, intel, icc

Is it possible to modify and assemble the `.s` file which can be generated by Intel's C compiler?
I know that it is possible with gcc via:

1. `gcc -S file.c`
2. modify `file.s`
3. `as file.s -o file.o`

However, if I try exactly the same with Intel's icc it will result in several errors and warnings. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: First let us know what you are modifying?

Comment: As stated in (2) I'm modifying the generated assembly file. Let's say I'm changing the order of two independent instructions.

Comment: What was the error? How can we know what was wrong without knowing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the assembly language is that there is no standard syntax, the most popular 2 syntax used to write assembly are the AT&T and Intel one.

Guess which one is being used by gcc, by default, and which one by Intel .

I suggest to use Intel syntax under gcc too so you can use just 1 syntax.

An example on how to generate asm with Intel syntax starting from sourcecode in `C`

```
gcc -S -masm=intel source.c
```

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I was generating the .s file via: icc -S -c file.c -masm=intel. However, the second step (i.e. (2) icc file.s -o file.o) failed. Removing -masm=intel from (1) resolves this issue. Is there a way to use icc to generate a .s file which uses intel syntax and assemble this .s file into a .o file?

Comment: @user1829358 see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367858/integrating-intels-icc-with-gcc