# What do all those numbers in ICC assembly output mean?

Tags: assembly, icc

When compiling with ICC, after every instruction is 2 dot-separated numbers prefixed with a hash sign. What does that mean?

[For example:](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'int+testFunction(int*+input,+int+length)+%7B%0A++int+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+length%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++sum+%2B%3D+input%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++%7D%0A++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc1301,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-masm%3Dintel',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+13.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
L__routine_start__Z12testFunctionPii_0:
testFunction(int*, int):
        push      rbp                                           #1.42
        mov       rbp, rsp                                      #1.42
        sub       rsp, 32                                       #1.42
        mov       QWORD PTR [-24+rbp], rdi                      #1.42
        mov       DWORD PTR [-16+rbp], esi                      #1.42
        mov       DWORD PTR [-32+rbp], 0                        #2.11
        mov       DWORD PTR [-28+rbp], 0                        #3.14
..B1.2:                         # Preds ..B1.3 ..B1.1
        mov       eax, DWORD PTR [-28+rbp]                      #3.19
        mov       edx, DWORD PTR [-16+rbp]                      #3.23
        cmp       eax, edx                                      #3.23
        jge       ..B1.4        # Prob 50%                      #3.23
...
```

Comment: The number before the dot seems to be the source line number. The hash sign is of course comment separator, so the assembler will ignore this stuff, it's just for information.

Comment: ...information for the debugger, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a comment and contains the line and column information of the origin source so you can follow where the instruction comes from. Depending on the optimization level and features like `out-of-order execution` the lines must not be in a natural order.